# Resizing a JFrame and all the contents inside

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, resize

I am making a game, and I am wondering if there is any way that you can resize the frame so that everything inside will also resize with it too?

Comment: What Layout Manager are you using?

Comment: I am using a null layout so that I can place the labels where I need to.

Comment: *"I am using a null layout so that I.."* ..can complicate things like resizing the GUI?  Learn how to use layouts.  They take care of these things properly.

Comment: Null layouts are only good when working with a designer. Otherwise use the Layouts supplied by the Swing Library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the job of the `LayoutManager`. Choose your `LayoutManager` carfully so that it arranges your components properly. For example, if you use a `BorderLayout`, the center component will be stretched to take all the space not occupied by NORTH-SOUTH or WEST-EAST.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose the right [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for you. You can have layouts within layouts by putting JPanels within JPanels.

If you find the Java Swing library annoying to work with like that, then I suggest using Netbeans IDE where you can design visually how your GUI will look like.